# exchange facebook access_token to stormpath access_token

Tags: stormpath

On my website a user can register/login with either username/password or facebook. The flow with username/password I have already got working. But I can not figure out how the flow should be with facebook login.

When username/password (this works):

- create a stormpath user
- exchange username/password for a stormpath access_token.
- store the stormpath access_token & refresh_token in a cookie.

With facebook I would **like to do** this:

- create a stormpath user from the aquired facebook access_token
- **Somehow exchange/generate a stormpath access_token**
- store the stormpath access_token & refresh_token in a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You currently cannot do that using Stormpath (I work there) -- this is something we're working on internally.

What you can do as a workaround right now, is this:

- When you exchange your Facebook Access Token for a Stormpath Account, you will have a 'Facebook' Account in the 'Facebook' Directory you've created with Stormpath.
- Create a copy of this user in a normal 'Stormpath' Directory.
- Generate a fresh Access / Refresh token for the 'normal' user in the Stormpath Directory, and use that token instead.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thx for quick response! But how can I generate a access/refresh token for a "normal" user in the stormpath directory. From my understanding I have to have the users username/password to get an access_token? Like this "POST /applications/APPLICATION_ID/oauth/token { grant_type=password&username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD }"

Comment: That's correct -- you NEED the username / password. This means you have to either set one yourself for the user on demand (bad), or have the user do the initial authentication, then store the refresh token (good).